# Conventions for zooming when developing a site

Tags: asp.net-mvc, zooming

Is there a convention for zoom when developing a site please? As background

1. advice seems to be to develop a site based on browsers being set to 100%
2. if I do this, then on a responsive site with full screen text it is simply too big and too little fits. I can within the CSS set Zoom: 70% and I get what I want
3. Question is, is there a convention? When I go to some web sites it seems to adjust the browser zoom to 90% by default. I am coding in ASP.NET MVC 4, is there a way to have the browser zoom adjust to say 90% when they enter my site, as if there is this would seem the best solution and I optimise the site for that.

Any advice on conventions and how to develop the site for the optimum zoom levels would be appreciated

Ian

Comment: I wouldn't hard code zoom levels. I don't think you can. I have very limited vision so any site I go to, I have to zoom in. Just make sure your design, and fonts especially respond to zooming.

Answer (score 0):

Thsi is precisely what "responsive design" is intended to solve. No longer thinking in terms of fixed pixels, but thinking in terms of percentages and ems.

Your site should adapt to whatever resolution the user has.

[Responsive Web Design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_web_design)